# C# WebBrowser Gmail Ads

Tags: c#, browser, gmail

I am creating a C# application that displays the google online applications, specifically Gmail in this situation. All is going well except that I do not know how to hide the ads that plugins that Firefox and Chrome have.

Anyone have any suggestions how I programmatically hide ads like the Firefox/Chrome plugins do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a CSS rule into the page with lists of the ads, and make the `display:none;`

Example:

```
<style type="text/css">
.classname,.anotherclassname,#idname{
display:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with css, can you give me an example?

Comment: Prob a vague question that I asked a while back that really requires a lot of research. Thanks for the follow up.

Comment: Actually no, I happened to know the answer off the top of my head :). Thanks for accepting though!