# Insert CSS using C# WebBrowser

Tags: c#, css

In this post:

[C# WebBrowser Gmail Ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195687/c-webbrowser-gmail-ads/5195708#5195708)

Buddy4j said:

> Insert a CSS rule into the page with
>   lists of the ads, and make the
>   display:none;

I'm not familiar with CSS and what I need to add. Anyone have an example as to what I am inserting and where?

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the CSS that's provided by [this site](http://www.floppymoose.com/).  You may have to manually inject

```
<link rel='stylesheet' />
```

into the `<head />` of the document the WebBrower control is set to use.